What is the algorithm for selecting the lines to show in a diff patch?
If I have two files, I've used the myer's distance algorithm to find the insert/del/equal lines between the two files.
I'd like to chunk the lines in the similar manner that git diffs produce. So no more than 3 LOCs that are equal, then followed by N lines that are either ins/del and < 3 eq. Followed up by either 3 eq LOC or to EOF.
I've gone through a few implementations but would like a find the most efficient one.

I suspect you will find each implementation uses its own algorithm. GNU diff algorithm seems much more hairy than busybox for example.
